# Can I call an overloaded constructor from another constructor of the same class in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

Can I call an overloaded constructor from another constructor of the same class in C#?

Comment: @Malay: What language are you talking about? If you are talking about java/c#, why should this be a question? The documentation should help you before you post a question. Sorry, if I am wrong in my understanding.

Comment: C# ..  I can call second constructor like this 
 foo(args) base()

but is it possible to do like this
foo()
{
//do something
foo(args)
//do something
}

Comment: @shahkalpesh, as the originators of this forum have often said, we do not discourage users from asking basic questions. So please refrain from RTFM like comments. 
@Malay, as @shahkalpesh said, it is certainly possible in Java/C#. Please be more specific about the language.

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829870/calling-constructor-from-other-constructor-in-same-class

Comment: What language? Malay obviously ... ;-)

Answer (score 250):

No, You can't do that, the only place you can call the constructor from another constructor in C# is immediately after ":" after the constructor.
for example

```
class foo
{
    public foo(){}
    public foo(string s ) { }
    public foo (string s1, string s2) : this(s1) {....}

}
```

Answer (score 95):

If you mean if you can do ctor chaining in C#, the answer is yes. [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829870/calling-constructor-from-other-constructor-in-same-class) has already been asked.

However it seems from the comments, it seems what you really intend to ask is 
'Can I call an overloaded constructor from **within** another constructor with pre/post processing?'
Although C# doesn't have the syntax to do this, you could do this with a common initialization function (like you would do in C++ which doesn't support ctor chaining)

```
class A
{
  //ctor chaining
  public A() : this(0)
  {  
      Console.WriteLine("default ctor"); 
  }

  public A(int i)
  {  
      Init(i); 
  }

  // what you want
  public A(string s)
  {  
      Console.WriteLine("string ctor overload" );
      Console.WriteLine("pre-processing" );
      Init(Int32.Parse(s));
      Console.WriteLine("post-processing" );
  }

   private void Init(int i)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("int ctor {0}", i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 49):

EDIT: According to the comments on the original post this is a C# question.

Short answer: yes, using the `this` keyword.

Long answer: yes, using the `this` keyword, and here's an example.

```
class MyClass
{
   private object someData;

   public MyClass(object data)
   {
      this.someData = data;
   }

   public MyClass() : this(new object())
   {
      // Calls the previous constructor with a new object, 
      // setting someData to that object
   }
}
```

Comment: the question was not about this, the question is asking if you can do this
public MyClass()

{
   // do something 
    // then let us call another constructor
   this(new object() ); /// you can't do this!
}

Comment: is it possible to class foo : fooBase{ public foo(string a) : this foo(a,null) : base(a) {} foo(string a, string b){}} ?

Comment: The question totally WAS about this - the terminology of the OP might have been off but this is what people want to know when they come here. +1

Answer (score 6):

In C# it is not possible to call another constructor from inside the method body.
You can call a base constructor this way: foo(args):base() as pointed out yourself.
You can also call another constructor in the same class: foo(args):this().

When you want to do something before calling a base constructor, it seems the construction of the base is class is dependant of some external things. If so, you should through arguments of the base constructor, not by setting properties of the base class or something like that