# Constructor can only be chained in initializer list, Why

Tags: c#, constructor

Why C# constructor can only be chained (one constructor calling another) in the initializer list? ex

```
constructor1()
{
    // do something
}

constructor2() : this()
{
    //do something else
}
```

Is there a reason that this is not allowed?

```
constructor1()
{
    // do something
}


constructor2()
{
    constructor1();
    // do something else.
}
```

Comment: Just a design choice. VB.NET lets you do the second form IIRC.

Comment: It's difficult to answer "why" a language is designed a certain way, unless someone on the design team wants to chime in.

Comment: Here's a way to handle in which order things are executed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/985587/2321042
Regarding the "why", [check this out](http://www.csharp411.com/constructor-chaining/).